# An object that should not be getting indexed is being indexed

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a very basic object that I'm searching over. My understanding is that the objects are indexed are filterd based on index_queryset method.  I would like to index only question that are not drafts and the author decided to publish. However, objects that do not meet this criteria are being indexed and when the search result for this objects are returned and I call .object on them I get a

```
ERROR Object could not be found in database for SearchResult '<SearchResult: qna.question (pk=u'869')>'
```

I'm pretty mystified as to why these objects are being indexed in the first place. Does any one know?

Follows is my SearchIndex, model, and object this is being indexed when it shouldn't be.

```
class QuestionIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return Question

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(is_draft=False,
                                           published_at__lte=datetime.now())


class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_draft = models.BoolenField(default=True)
    text = models.TextField()


Question.objects.create(title="shouldn't show", is_draft=False, text="Really shuldn't show")
```

But after I update the indexes and run

```
SearchQueyset().filter(content="shouldn't show")
```

I get a search result with objects with is_draft=false in it, and when I do search_result.object I get that error. Am I missing something? Can any one explain this to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to run `rebuild_index` instead of `update_index`? It seems like there is an old object in your search index that needs to be cleared.

Comment: So running update_index fixes the issue. However, I have it set to use a signal processor. And I've always had this set. How can I have old objects in the search index?

Comment: I think the index_queryset function doesn't apply to the signal processor (I could be wrong though). You may have to use a custom signal processor that excludes objects with is_draft=False